# Shiny. Plot axis labels as custom names, not variable names (from data)

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am working in Shiny and making an interactive plot with ggplot2. Using pull down menus on the UI the user can change what variables are plotted on the x and y axes. I would like the axes labels on the plot to represent the labels within the pull down menu, not the variable names from the actual dataset. The labels in the pull down menu are easier to interpret.

I can get this to work on my machine by specifying two lists (one for each axis) in the global workspace prior to running my Shiny app.

In the global workspace for one axis

```
predChoices <- c("Cabezon Standard Length (mm)" = "predlength", 
             "Cabezon Mass (g)" = "predmass")
```

and then in the server.R when I specify the axis label in ggplot

```
scale_x_continuous(paste("\n",names(predChoices[predChoices == input$predVariable])))
```

where predVariable is the name of the pull-down widget in the UI.R. This code labels the axes nicely with the much more descriptive labels.

The problem is that using this workaround not all the requirements for the Shiny App are included within the app, making it hard to post to the web or share with others, because of the need for the initial code to setup the naming lists within the global workspace.

Is there a means within Shiny of making the axis labels reactive, but allow them to have custom names rather than the actual variable names (from the datafile), without having to make the specification in the global workspace prior to running the app?

Thanks,
Nate